# calling fscanf in assembly using nasm

Tags: assembly, file-io, nasm, scanf

I am trying to read 3 values from a file with a format as integer character whitespace integer. For example:

5, 3

In that **exact** format i.e: no whitespace after the 5, a whitespace after the comma and no whitespace after the 3.

I successfully called fopen to open the file and I used fgetc to access the same file and print its contents. Now I am trying to use fscanf()

I read that to call a C function from assembly you have to push the parameters in reverse order onto the stack, below is my code to do this

```
    lea eax, [xValue]
    push eax
    lea eax, [comma]
    push eax
    lea eax, [yValue]
    push eax
    mov eax, [format] ;defined as [format db "%d %c %d", 0] in the data section
    push eax
    mov eax, ebx ; move handle to file into eax
    push eax
    call _fscanf
```

At this point I am assuming the above is equivalent to:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d %c %d", &yValue, &comma, &xValue);
```

If it is equivalent to the above, how do I access the values read? I know I'm accessing the file correctly since I was able to print out the individual characters by calling fgetc, but for clarity below is my code to open the file

```
    mov eax, fileMode
    push eax
    mov eax, fileName
    push eax
    call _fopen                
    mov ebx, eax ;store file pointer
```

Any help/advice is much appreciated. Thanks.

*<sub>Edited to add…</sub>*

The answer provided the solution. Posting the code below for anyone else who has this problem.

```
section .data

    fname db "data.txt",0
    mode db "r",0                                ;;set file mode for reading
    format db "%d%c %d", 0

;;--- end of the data section -----------------------------------------------;;

section .bss
    c resd 1
    y resd 1
    x resd 1
    fp resb 1

section .text
    extern _fopen
    global _main

_main:        
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

    mov eax, mode
    push eax
    mov eax, fname
    push eax
    call _fopen                
    mov [fp] eax ;store file pointer

    lea eax, [y]
    push eax        
    lea eax, [c] 
    push eax
    lea eax, [x]        
    push eax
    lea eax, [format]
    push eax
    mov eax, [fp] 
    push eax
    call _fscanf

    ;at this point x, y and c has the data

    mov eax,0
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your scanf() format string is wrong.  Should be "%d%c %d".  Why do you care about the comma anyway?  Why not just use "%d, %d" and ditch the comma variable.

Also, you are trying to load eax with a value from the first bytes of [format], you need to push the pointer to format.

Finally, you don't want the brackets around the memory addresses, unless your assembler is weird you are pushing the wrong addresses.

```
lea eax, xvalue
push eax
lea eax, yValue
push eax
lea eax, format
push eax
call _fscanf
```

Now you should have the values you want in xvalue and yvalue

Comment: When I tried lea eax, xvalue nasm gives me the following error "invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Comment: that's fine the, just the way that assembler works, use the brackets